# Crear una matriz bidimensional en consola, c#

Tags: c#, console

Necesito crear una aplicación en consola, donde me pida ingresar un número que será el tamaño de la matriz.

Lo que me falta hacer es que aparezcan los 1,2 y 3 al momento de imprimir la matriz. Así como se muestra en la imagen.
Sólo que ya no supe cómo.

***Alguna idea?***

**Aquí está mi código:**(disculpen tan feo código, así fue como lo voy entendiendo)

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             int i, j, k, l, m, n, o;
             for (;; )
             {
                 n= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (n==0)
                 {
                     break;
                 }
                 int[][] arr = new int[n][];
                 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                 {
                     for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                     {
                         arr[i] = new int[n];
                         arr[i][j]=1;
                     }
                 }
                 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                 {
                     for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                     {
                         if (j==0)
                         {
                             Console.Write("   "+arr[i][j]);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             Console.Write("    "+ arr[i][j]);
                         }
                         //Console.Write("\n");
                     }
                     Console.Write("\n");
                 }
             }
      }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de hacer esto, la más simple a mi parecer es pensar que son varias matrices, una más pequeña que la otra y todas están sobrepuesta. Y en donde se debe dibujar el perímetro.

Por ejemplo con este código
(lo importante es el IF )

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int largo = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < largo; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == largo - 1 || i == 0 || i == largo - 1)
            {
                Console.Write($" 1 ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write($" 0 ");
            }
                   
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

Obtienes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, ahora hay que dibujar el perímetro de la matriz interior, para eso debemos encontrar una función que sea capaz de retornar el valor correspondiente.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int largo = 5;
    DibujarMatriz(largo);
}

static void DibujarMatriz(int largo)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < largo; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < largo; j++)
        {
            Console.Write($" {GetValor(i,j,largo,1)} ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

}

public static int GetValor(int i, int j, int largo, int n)
{
    if (j == 0 || j == largo - 1 || i == 0 || i == largo - 1)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        return GetValor(i-1, j-1, largo-2, n+1);
    }
}
```

GetValor es una función recursiva, que al no cumplir la condición (de ser perímetro) se llama nuevamente con una matriz más pequeña. Como debe ser una matriz más pequeña a 'i' y 'j' le restamos 1 y el largo es menos 2, por lo que la disminuimos por la derecha, por la izquierda, por arriba y por abajo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer de cuenta que la matriz es un tablero de ajedrez (no necesariamente de 8x8) y calcular la distancia de [Chebyshov](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distancia_de_Chebyshov) entre la casilla actual y el centro del tablero.

Entonces, para una matriz de 3x3 obtendrías lo siguiente:

```
111
101
111
```

Bien, entonces puedes tomar la mitad del ancho redondeada hacía arriba y le restas la distancia a cada elemento:

```
222     111     111
222  -  101  =  121
222     111     111
```

Solo falta encontrar el centro. Por ejemploas posiciones de una matriz de 3x3 son:

```
 012
0...
1...
2...
```

Nota que la posición del centro es exactamente `(3 - 1) / 2`. O lo que es lo mismo, `(ancho - 1) / 2`. Afortunadamente está fórmula también sirve para matrices de dimensiones pares que no tienen un centro exacto.

El código queda así:

```
static int Distancia(int n, int x, int y)
{
    float medio = (n - 1) / 2.0f;
    float absX = Math.Abs(x - medio);
    float absY = Math.Abs(y - medio);
    return (int)Math.Max(absX, absY);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int largo = 8;
    int mitad = (int)Math.Ceiling(largo / 2.0f);
    for (int y = 0; y < largo; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < largo; x++)
        {
            Console.Write(mitad - Distancia(largo, x, y));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##dZE9T8MwEIb3/IpTJ1tNQmFDgQGVkUpIDIAQg5u6wZJjS7aLHFX57cEfJXFKuSH@yPvc3XuudVFLRYfhoJlo4KXThrZVltWcaA3PSjaKtHDMMnChDTGsBiYMPDJ3EDUjyJ9EHi5tXDoc1Mfw9bHnkhho6Y5JuAckoIBrDFdwU6721ZmKbPWbE22I@SofthpZJw4kvqB8T5XdBaWi5qAE@CZxEG6IRb5EHvCTsp/Z@5Zs57IygbRRbigfn0BUo89Neafc/fCWbqvZ9eh0LLumjLtUKALRedLm5EyqQEHn8FXllrtYxG2XSzzqpjZmlI2UnSibUn9JH2sptOS0fFXMUHRqvkheOKTK/et2OGk6Tu7fTE9MULRYJED/O@x@GH4A).